# Cancel event triggering (blur) from another element's event (click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a few rows with text, which I can "edit" by replacing the row inline with an input, which gets the text from the row as its value attribute.

When the input looses focus, the previous text is restored.

When pressing return (keyCode 13), the new text is saved and will be written in the row.

Now, for the users who don't know to press return for saving the text, I want to add a "Save" button right next to the input field. But when pressing it, the blur event of the input field is getting fired first, discarding the changes.

So is there an easy way, that the .click() event of the button can cancel the .blur() event on the input field? Perhaps an "don't execute other events" or can I perhaps see in the blur event, which events will get called next to cancel it?

Here is a jsfiddle to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ykY5X/
(I'm working in Firefox (latest Nightly), where the button click won't work. I just tested the jsfiddle also in chrome, where also the keyup won't work as expected.)

```
$('#showEdit').click(function() {
    $('#row').data('text',$('#row').text());
    $('#row').html('<input type="text" id="editInput" /> <span id="editSave">Save</span>');
    $('#editInput').val($('#row').data('text')).focus();
});

$('#row').delegate('#editInput','keyup',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keycode == 13) $('#editSave').click();
}).delegate('#editSave','click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('#row').text($('#editInput').val());
}).delegate('#editInput','blur',function() {
    $('#row').text($('#row').data('text'));
});
```

Comment: cant you just save the value when the user hits edit, then save it again when on onblur, then the save button function compares the two values and if they are different, changes it to the last value saved from on blur?

Comment: Was a great idea! Unfortunately, the `click` event won't fire, as soon as the `blur` event removes the button. It only fires the `mousedown` event of the button. With a bit of temporary data, it works nice :) Thank you!

Comment: Glad i could offer an approach to which you could work from :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final working solution is this:

```
$('#showEdit').click(function() {
    $('#row').data('textOriginal',$('#row').text());
    $('#row').data('textSave',$('#row').text());
    $('#row').html('<input type="text" id="editInput" /> <span id="editSave">Save</span>');
    $('#editInput').val($('#row').data('textOriginal')).focus();
});

$('#row').delegate('#editInput','keyup',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keycode == 13) {
        $('#row').data('textSave',$(this).val());
        $('#editSave').click();
    }
}).delegate('#editSave','mousedown',function() {
    $('#row').data('textSave',$('#editInput').val());
}).delegate('#editSave','click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if ($('#row').data('textOriginal') == $('#row').data('textSave')) {
        $('#row').text($('#row').data('textOriginal'));
        return;
     }

    $('#row').text($('#row').data('textSave'));

}).delegate('#editInput','blur',function() {
    $('#editSave').click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RSUdx/

Answer (score 2):

You can use some delay before the code inside `blur` event handler gets executed. On Save button click you can cancel the `blur` timer so that it will not be executed.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykY5X/6/)**

```
var blurTimer;
$('#showEdit').click(function() {
        $('#row').data('text',$('#row').text());
        $('#row').html('<input type="text" id="editInput" /> <span id="editSave">Save</span>');
        $('#editInput').val($('#row').data('text')).focus();
});

$('#row').delegate('#editInput','keyup',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keycode == 13){
       $('#editSave').click();
    }
}).delegate('#editSave','click',function(e) {
    clearTimeout(blurTimer);
    $('#row').text($('#editInput').val());
}).delegate('#editInput','blur',function() {
    blurTimer = setTimeout(function(){
       $('#row').text($('#row').data('text'));
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: @Wulf - Hope this helped you solve your porblem. If yes, please mark this as an answer.

Comment: I upvoted it, because it's a possible solution. See my final solution for how I did it in the end.

Comment: You solution will trigger the `click` event handler twice and also if you want to execute any logic only on blur `event` you cannot do that.

Comment: What browser do you use? Here in Firefox the `click` event is only triggered once (by the `blur` event), because the button will be removed before the `mouseup` (and finally `click`) event is being cached by the button. For the single `blur` event functionallity (so no button click or anything else) there is the `if`-block `textOriginal == textSave` in the `click` event, which is being called, when no change was made and the input field blured.

Answer (score 1):

I think u can try this:

```
$('#showEdit').click(function() {
    $('#row').data('text',$('#row').text());
    $('#row').html('<input type="text" id="editInput" /> <span id="editSave">Save</span>');
    $('#editInput').val($('#row').data('text')).focus();
});

$('#row').delegate('#editInput','keyup',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keycode == 13) $('#editSave').click();
}).delegate('#editSave','click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('#row').text($('#editInput').val());

}).delegate('#editInput','blur',function() {
    if($('#editSave').click())
         $('#row').text($('#editInput').val());
    else
    $('#row').text($('#row').data('text'));
});
```

Comment: If I understand it right, this will always save the new text. (F.e. clicking somewhere in the window, it tries to execute the click() function, and that will always succeed)

Comment: The trouble with this is that the text is saved even after onblur. I thought you wanted it to save just when the user hits enter or the save button, in which case see my comment on your question

Answer (score -1):

`.unbind` allows u to unbind.[[docs](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)]

**EDIT**

Use `keydown` in place of `keyup`

Comment: You didn't read my question or look at my jsfiddle to see what my problem is. If unbind (which I know of course) can help me, please explain how.

Comment: Ohh k i will get back to u soon with a fiddle :D